# Reassociate all related models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Ok, We f&^%$**&ed up.

We lost a bunch of user records.  At some point, an integration file ran which re-inserted some of the lost records.

The problem is that the new users have a different ID than the original user, so all the existing related content for the old User id has been orphaned.  I now need to go back in and reassociate all the orphaned stuff to the new User id.  It won't be enough to simply give the new user the old Id from backup, because there will be new content associated to the new User Id.

We know the reflect_on_all_associations method, but that is hard to use for finding stuff.  However, this could be a starting point for a script of some kind.

Any clues on how to have a method return all models related to a particular model based on associations, without having to specify or know those associations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to use reflect_all_associations: You can iterate through the associations, select only the has_many and has_one, and then update those records. Here's a helper class to do the job which you can execute by calling AssociationFixer.new(user_to_destroy, original_user_id).fix_associations:

```
class AssociationFixer
  USER_ASSOCIATIONS = User.reflect_on_all_associations

  def initialize(user_to_destroy, original_user_id)
    @user_to_destroy = user_to_destroy
    @original_user_id = original_user_id
  end

  def fix_associations
    USER_ASSOCIATIONS.each do |association|
      next if association.options.has_key? :through
      if association.macro == :has_many
        fix_has_many(association)
      elsif association.macro == :has_one
        fix_has_one(association)
      end
    end
  end

  def fix_has_many(association)
    @user_to_destroy.send(association.name).each do |record|
      if association.options.has_key? :foreign_key
        record.send(assignment_method(association.foreign_key), @original_user_id)
      else
        record.user_id = @original_user_id
      end
      record.save
    end
  end

  def fix_has_one(association)
    if association.options.has_key? :foreign_key
      @user_to_destroy.send(association.name).send(assignment_method(association.foreign_key), @original_user_id)
    else
      @user_to_destroy.send(assignment_method(association.name.user_id), @original_user_id)
    end
    record.save
  end

  def assigment_method(method_name)
    method_name.to_s + '='
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem for SQL. I would look at importing your backup tables into the database in a separate table, if it's possible to join them on a column, maybe email or user_name or something. Then you can run a select based on the old id and update to the new id. Best of luck!

Comment: The only issue with this approach is that the associations would need to be known by me.  Rails already knows all the associations and so I'm hoping for an easy way to grab all associated records using model association.  Thanks, though!